# How and When do Ocelotes spawn? Minecraft (1.12.1)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've burned down a section of 600 by 700 blocks of Jungle in hopes of getting an Ocelote but after an hour and a half, I haven't even seen one. Let alone tame one.

Does anyone have any idea how and where they spawn? I know they need grass blocks and jungle biome but nothing in particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ocelots spawn in jungles biomes on both grass blocks and leaf blocks. If they don't spawn, you should try to kill all other animals. The game has a mob cap which prevents more mobs from spawning when this cap is reached. To get more animals spawning, make sure that both your jungle and your world spawn are cleared from any animals and you should see ocelots and parrots spawn in your jungle.

Comment: Killing out all of the animals around huh, there were like 5 or 6 parrots and 2 sheep so that would make sense. Imma try it out and approve the answer if it works !

Comment: UPDATE: got 3 ocelots and Im breeding them now! Thanks for your info it seems it helped.